# select one table and sum row in another table with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two table is Product and Order, I want select all product and count number product in Order.
Example:

```
Product
ID   |   Name   | ....
P001  ProductA    ....
P002  ProductB    ....
P003  ProductC    ....
P004  ProductD    ....

Order
ID   | CustomerID | ...
O001   C001
O002   C002

OrderDetails
ID   | OrderID | ProductID | Quantity | ....
1      O001      P001        2          ....
2      O001      P002        1          ....
3      O002      P002        4          ....
4      O002      P004        1          ....

Result is:
ID   |   Name   | Count | ....
P001  ProductA    2       ....
P002  ProductB    5       ....
P003  ProductC    0       ....
P004  ProductD    1       ....
```

I try code below but is wrong

```
db.tblProducts
  .Join(db.tblOrderDetails, p => p.ProductID, o => o.ProductID, (p, o) => new { Product = p, OrderDetails = o })
  .Select(x => new { x.Product , x.OrderDetails  })
  .ToList();
```

Parsed data to view `{ Product  = MvcWebProject.Entities.tblProduct, OrderDetails   = MvcWebProject.Entities.tblOrderDetails }`, but I can't select value.

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.products)
{
    <p>@item.Product</p> //'object' does not contain a definition for 'Product'
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: If you solved your problem you should post it as an answer, not append it to your question.

Comment: My reputation not enough for post an answer :D

Comment: @QHu91_IT ***anyone*** can post an answer, it doesn't matter what your reputation is.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, hope this gets you started:

```
from product in db.tblProducts
let summedCount=(from orderDetail in product.OrderDetails
                 select orderDetail.Quantity).Sum()
select new {Id=product.Id,Name=product.Name,Count=summedCount}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create new model contain tblProduct and count

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Prod = new tblProduct();
    }
    public tblProduct Prod { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Count { get; set; }
}
```

Code in controller

```
var products = db.tblProducts
                     .Select(x => new Product { 
                             Prod = x, 
                             Count = db.tblOrderDetails
                                       .Where(z => z.ProductID == x.ProductID)
                                       .Sum(z => z.Quantity) })
                     .ToList();
return View(products)
```

and in view

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.Prod.MSP</p>
    <p>@{int? c = 0;if (item.Count == null) { c = 0; } else { c = item.Count; }}@c</p>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select Product.ID, Product.Name, SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) as [Count] from Product inner join
OrderDetails on Product.ID=OrderDetails.Quantity group by Product.ID;
```